# How to make object of Parcel2 class in main function

Tags: c++

I've separate implementation and defination of methods. Now i doesn't understand how to make object/instance of Parcel2 class in Main.cpp file. I also write in Main.cpp **Parcel2::Parcel2(2);** but it log saying constructor cannot call directly. kindly guide me.

Parcel2.h

```
#ifndef PARCEL2_H
#define PARCEL2_H

class Parcel2
{
    private:
        // Declare data members
        int id; 

    public:
        // Constructor
        Parcel2(int id);

        // Setter function
        void setID(int id); 

        // getter function
        int getID();

    protected:
};

#endif
```

Parcel2.cpp

```
#include "Parcel2.h"

// Defination of constructor
Parcel2::Parcel2(int id) {
    this->id = id;
}       
// Defination of setter
void Parcel2::setID(int id) {
    this->id = id;
}

// Defination of getter 
int Parcel2::getID() {
    return id;
}
```

Main7.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Parcel2.h"

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // how to make object
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to create a `Parsel2` object on the stack (as a local variable), you can just declare a variable with an integer argument.  (The integer argument is needed because your constructor requires an argument.)  For example:

```
Parcel2 obj(2);
```

Here is an alternative C++ 11 syntax, which some (me) find easier to parse:

```
auto obj = Parcel2(2);
```

If instead you want to dynamically allocate a `Parsel2`, you need to allocate it with `new`:

```
Parcel2 * obj = new Parcel2(2);
```

And once again, an alternative syntax:

```
auto obj = new Parcel2(2);
```

As a final note, please consider assigning class members using a *member initialization list*:

```
Parcel2::Parcel2(int id) : id(id)
{}
```